# Combination of taking $m$ snacks from $n$ choices

Tags: probability, combinations

Assume there are infinity amount of snacks in a store and I am going to buy $m$ snacks from $n$ different kinds of snacks (of course I can have repeated choices). How many combination of choices I can make?

I found difficulties because choices can be repeated. The answer is not simply $n^m$. Since it is the same that I buy chips at choice $1$, candies at choice $2$ or chips at choice $2$, candies at choice $1$.

Comment: Follow the hint Barry Cipra gave. Stars and Bars is the key method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:  Take a look at [Stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: thx. I got the answer.